# Multiple column vs multiple tables for foreign keys mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table (products)

```
id->PK
product_name
```

I have another table (ingredients)

```
id->PK
ingredient_name
```

I have a third table (purchase_order)

```
id->PK
```

This purchase order can have many lines of either products or ingredients or both.

Now what would be the best approach design-wise? I will be doing all sorts of queries within these tables. I prefer Approach 1 even though there will be many null values but would like to hear your thoughts on this too. These is no option to have a super table which will work as a parent of products and ingredients.

**Approach 1:**

Creating the table purchase_order_line with the following fields

```
purchase_order_id
product_id(nullable references products)
ingredient_id(nullable references ingredients)
```

**Approach 2:**

creating 2 tables:

purchase_order_products

```
purchase_order_id
product_id(references products)
```

purchase_order_ingredients

```
purchase_order_id
ingredient_id(references ingredients)
```

Comment: Can't you merge products and ingridients into a single table? You could distinguish between them in the products table using a product type field. The invoice table would have to reference the product table only.

Comment: The tables are so diverse that they needed separation. Unfortunately, that's not an option.

Comment: And what if you need to add a 3rd type to the existing 2? Going to add new fields or tables and rewrite all the queries? Both approaches are extremely inflexible.

Comment: I wouldn't need a 3rd type. Basically, this is being used for months now. We are adding more functionalities and hence need to create this module which will allow the customers to order both from a single order. We could offer them to create separate PO for each type but doing from a single place could be easier for them. If we ever need a 3rd type, this will come with it's own PO too :)